# Issue importing a ONNX model that use lstm in Unity

Tags: c#, tensorflow, unity-game-engine, lstm, unityscript

I am trying to import an .onnx model in Unity, however I am getting an error; in the project I have both barracuda and ML-Agents updated and I cannot simplify the .onnx model or use the internet for the application. Do any of you know of something that can help me?

Thanks!

this is the .onnx model import error

```
Asset import failed, "Assets/models tflite/alphabetonnx.onnx" > OnnxImportException: Unknown type Loop encountered while parsing layer StatefulPartitionedCall/sequential_37/lstm_109/while_loop:0.

Unity.Barracuda.ONNX.ONNXModelConverter.Err (Unity.Barracuda.Model model, System.String layerName, System.String message, System.String extendedMessage, System.String debugMessage) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.barracuda@3.0.0/Barracuda/Runtime/ONNX/ONNXModelConverter.cs:3434)
Unity.Barracuda.ONNX.ONNXModelConverter.ConvertOnnxModel (Onnx.ModelProto onnxModel) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.barracuda@3.0.0/Barracuda/Runtime/ONNX/ONNXModelConverter.cs:2954)
Unity.Barracuda.ONNX.ONNXModelConverter.Convert (Google.Protobuf.CodedInputStream inputStream) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.barracuda@3.0.0/Barracuda/Runtime/ONNX/ONNXModelConverter.cs:170)
Unity.Barracuda.ONNX.ONNXModelConverter.Convert (System.String filePath) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.barracuda@3.0.0/Barracuda/Runtime/ONNX/ONNXModelConverter.cs:98)
Unity.Barracuda.ONNXModelImporter.OnImportAsset (UnityEditor.AssetImporters.AssetImportContext ctx) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.barracuda@3.0.0/Barracuda/Editor/ONNXModelImporter.cs:65)
UnityEditor.AssetImporters.ScriptedImporter.GenerateAssetData (UnityEditor.AssetImporters.AssetImportContext ctx) (at <53ddbed73faf4fe3b980a493ab4e6639>:0)

(Filename: C:\build\output\unity\unity\Modules\AssetPipelineEditor\Public\ScriptedImporter.cpp Line: 220)
```